# Is it possible to limit or restrict the scope of C# code that can be executed from a DLL?

Tags: c#, .net, security, sandbox

I am working on a project where I will allow users to write some code, which will be compiled, loaded and ran, this code will allow the users to control certain parts of the application. However, with this just allowing them to insert C# into the running app, there are certain restrictions I'd preferably like to have in place.

Are there any ways that you can run a piece of code but lets say block out any `System.Threading` use or any `System.IO` use?

I know going through the code and removing any references would be possible, but I am sure there would be ways around that. Before writing this, I'd at least like to check there isn't an easier, more effective way.

I have googled but either I am looking in the wrong place or asking the wrong question. I do know, however, that you Stack Overflow people are geniuses. Any ideas?

Thanks, and any answer would be appreciated greatly!

Comment: "Sandboxing" is a common term of art for what it sounds like you're trying to do. That might help you in your Googling.

Comment: Sandboxing/CAS is the way to go.  Even if you remove all references, there may be unsafe things possible, e.g. `Environment.Exit` might not be wanted but is in mscorlib.dll

Comment: Looking at Sandboxing/CAS and I think it _is_ the way to go. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Code Access Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff527276.aspx) might be what you are looking for.

Comment: AFAICT you can't restrict the creation of new threads using Code Access Security to avoid things like unhandled exceptions in add-in created threads, even when "isolated" in a new AppDomain.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going through the code and removing all the individual references, why not just limit the project references?  Also, you might be able to leverage .NET permissions on a system by using the .NET framework configuration snap in to manage access to GAC, domain apps, etc. based on various options.  (start > run > mscorcfg.msc to launch it)  I don't know what the newer 4.0 option is to replace that configuration utility however.  EDIT: To take it one step further you could, for example run the entered code with a service user account and limit that user's code access via this utility.

Comment: Unfortunately the main app which loads the assembly and uses the class object requires the full permissions. I think that I might be able to find a way of running it, safely, with AppDomains. thanks